# Nodejs and Id Params search (get) method mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, api, routes, searchbar

I am trying to create a search function that auto populates my form with the corresponding record from my database and get API.

Here is my route

```
//Get number and dets to page
    router.get("/sop/:id", function (request, response, next) {
      response.render("test", { output: request.params.id });
    });

   

 

        //Elements i want to print my results to 
            const sopN = document.getElementById("sop");
            const CustName = document.getElementById("cusName");
            const button = document.getElementById("subBtn");
     button.onclick = function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          const url = "http://localhost:6600/api/sopId/";
          let sopSearch = document.getElementById("sop");
          fetch(`${url}/${sopSearch.value}`, {
        method: "GET",
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json));
    };
```

The error says I'm getting is:

> "http://localhost:6600/api/sopId/(record)" 404 not found and uncaught in promise Syntax error: unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Please any and all assistance will be is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your URL.

Your route is "/sop/:id", so something like "http://localhost:6600/api/sop/1", but your URL is "http://localhost:6600/api/sopId/" to which you're appending sopSearch.value turning it into "http://localhost:6600/api/sopId/1".

So change this const url = "http://localhost:6600/api/sopId/"; to const url = "http://localhost:6600/api/sop/";

Comment: So I have used this url "http://localhost:6600/api/sop/" as the request that shows all the records in my db, so if I change my url I will have to change the other one as well .

Comment: I see what you were referring to i realised i copied the wrong path the one that i am using is this //Get one sopnumber
router.route("/sopId/:sopNumbe").get((request, response) => {
  dboperation.getQuote(request.params.sopNumbe).then((result) => {
    response.json(result[0]);
  });
});